# CSS flex: using row-reverse with responsive media queries

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having trouble using `row-reverse` in a flex grid layout when using media queries. The column order is reversed normally, but when the media query changes the column width to 100%, the column order is no longer reversed.

How can I update my css to keep the column order reversed on small screens?

```css
.row {
 display: flex;
 flex: 0 1 auto;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
[class*='col-'] {
 flex: 1;
}
.row-reverse {
 flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.col, [class*='col-'] {
 -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
 flex-basis: 100%;
 max-width: 100%; 
}

@media (min-width: 600px) { 
 .col-3 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  max-width: 25%; 
 }
}
```

```html
<h3>Resize browser to less than 600px to see the ordering issue</h3>

<div class="row row-reverse">

    <div class="col-3 padding0-5">

        <p>First</p>

    </div> <!-- /.col-3 -->

    <div class="col-3 padding0-5">

        <p>Second</p>

    </div> <!-- /.col-3 -->

    <div class="col-3 padding0-5">

        <p>Third</p>

    </div> <!-- /.col-3 -->

    <div class="col-3 padding0-5">

        <p>Fourth</p>

    </div> <!-- /.col-3 -->

</div> <!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: If you reverse the order on every device, shouldn't you just output the html in the correct order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `flex-direction: column-reverse` on `< 600px` device size. Also you can write this in less code you just have to change row/column reverse.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
[class*='col-'] {
  flex: 1;
}
.reverse {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .reverse {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row reverse">
  <div class="col-3 padding0-5"><p>First</p></div>
  <div class="col-3 padding0-5"><p>Second</p></div>
  <div class="col-3 padding0-5"><p>Third</p></div>
  <div class="col-3 padding0-5"><p>Fourth</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just change your `flex-wrap` to  `wrap-reverse;`

```css
.row {
 display: flex;
 flex: 0 1 auto;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
[class*='col-'] {
 flex: 1;
}
.row-reverse {
 flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.col, [class*='col-'] {
 -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
 flex-basis: 100%;
 max-width: 100%; 
}

@media (min-width: 600px) { 
 .col-3 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  max-width: 25%; 
 }
}
```

```html
<h3>Resize browser to less than 600px to see the ordering issue solved</h3>

<div class="row row-reverse">
  <div class="col-3 padding0-5"><p>First</p></div> <!-- /.col-3 -->
  <div class="col-3 padding0-5"><p>Second</p></div> <!-- /.col-3 -->
  <div class="col-3 padding0-5"><p>Third</p></div> <!-- /.col-3 -->
  <div class="col-3 padding0-5"><p>Fourth</p></div> <!-- /.col-3 -->
</div> <!-- /.row -->
```